# Javascript not accepting percentage (%) in the URL query param

Tags: javascript

we are writing javascript to parse URL hostname and path with below code. When the URL contains the percentage, it's not able to parse and throwing error **"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid URL string."**

So how we can parse the URL with contains of percentage: **https://abcd.com/dav?offer=30%off**

```
 addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  console.log('request :  ', request)
  let requestURL = new URL(request.url)
  console.log('REQUEST URL :  ', requestURL)
  return new Response("Hello world")
}
```

Comment: Can be resolved by using ```encodeURI()``` for URL or ```encodeURIComponent()``` for query string.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is a special character in URLs. You need `%25` to express the meaning "A percentage character" inside a URL.

Encode plain strings with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before mashing them into URLs.

Better, use an API designed for building URLs instead of reinventing the wheel.

```js
const base = "https://abcd.com/dav"
const url = new URL(base);
url.searchParams.append("offer", "30%off");
document.body.append(url);
```